# How to compare data with VBA code?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there a VBA formula that will compare the dates, and the similar words, between the two data sets? For example, if it contains "Ter" and "1/9/18", then I can find out that the location is "Grass".

My goal is to find the cells where the "Dates" are the same and where "Away Club" or "Home Club" matches "Organization", to ultimately find the location.

I have two Excel sheets and I need to find the rows which are comparable.

- I have a "Date" column that needs to be an exact match on both sheets.
- In addition I have two columns and need to match up with one column on the second sheet.

  - They are not exact matches, but both include similar words for example, "Ter".

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1409656/edit) to give us the code you have so far as well as an explanation of how it fails to achieve the desired result? Also can you clarify if you are looking for VBA code or a formula? ("VBA formula" is kind of ambiguous)

Comment: You definitely want to include a link to your previous question and an explanation of what you're hoping to achieve by posting another question - as soon as somebody notices it, this one's going to get flagged as a duplicate. I'm surprised you didn't include any of the additional information that you eventually gave me in comments on my answer, as I recommended there that you do. And I'm also surprised that you've still done evidently no research and made no effort on your own to solve the problem. That said, it looks like you lucked out and got a potentially good answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSE formula in **H2**:

`=IF( G2<>"", IFERROR( INDEX( D$2:D$100, SMALL( IF( F2=A$2:A$100, IF( IFERROR( SEARCH(G2, B$2:B$100), IFERROR( SEARCH( G2, C$2:C$100), FALSE)), ROW(D$2:D$100) - ROW(D$2) + 1)),1)), "Not Found"),"")`

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this a CSE array formula.
Then copy drag the formula down however far.
All the ranges correspond to the OP sample sheet.

The search is

- Insensitive to case.
- Finds partial Team Names. (`Bea` finds the team `Bears`)
- Can use wild cards `*?` (`B*R` or `B??r` finds `Bears`)

  - `*` matches zero or more characters (`Bears*` matches `Bears`)
  - `?` matches exactly one character (`Bears?` does not match, no character after the `s` in the team name for `?` to match)